# How to get paged and sorted groups with spring-data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, grouping, paging

My backend hast to return data in the following structure:

```
     data: [{
        key: "Group 1",
        items: [ ... ],         
        count: 3,               
    },{
        key: "Group 2",
        items: [ ... ],         
        count: 9,               
    } ...]
```

This data must be sortable and pageable. The following code is doing that:

```
public Page<Report> getReports(Integer skip, Integer take, String sortParams, String group) {

     Pageable pageable = createPageable(skip, take, sortParams); 
     Specifications<Report> filters = (Specifications<Report>) getFilters();

     return this.reportRepository.findAll(filters, pageable);

}

@Repository
public interface ReportRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Report, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Report> {

}
```

Additionally i want to group the result by attributes of the report class. Is there anyway to do this with spring-data? I couldn't find anything in their API.

Comment: Please add your entity structure and exact JSON result.

Comment: The entity structure doesn't really matter. I need a grouped Page Result and looking for a generic spring solution.

Answer (score 1):

The question is - could you get the result you wanted by querying the DB directly, where *group by* is available?

As a rule of thumb, if you can get a result in the required format from the DB, you can always get the result in Spring Data using Native Query, and store the result in a POJO written for it.

In the example below, I assumed you have a new Object just for storing the result, called **Result**. Since you didn't specify exactly the structure of the result of the query you would use in the DB, I didn't supply a class definition of Result. The query I used was just basic group by, which you should replace with your own.

In the repository interface, create a native query with group by:

```
@Repository
public interface ReportRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Report, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Report> {

    @Query(value="Select grp, count(grp) from report group by grp", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Result> findAggregatedResults();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As result i want to have a org.springframework.data.domain.Page Object. So i need something like: Page<Report> findAggregatedResults(Specifications<Report> filter, Pageable pageable, List<String> groupBy);

Comment: If you wish to paginate, you just need to ask for List<Result> one page at a time. Look at how it's done here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting. The idea is to start from what each result row should have, and leave the pagination to get you the next X rows in a regular list.

Comment: There is not mentioned how to group the result by various attributes.

Comment: I mentioned how to group the results in the original answer. You write a POJO for the answer you want, write a group by query in native SQL and attach it in the repository to a method that returns a List<POJO>. You can have this list of results paged regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Late here,

But if someone still lingering around how to use GROUP BY with Pageable in Hibernate Queries, they can use -

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT " +
        "new com.example.result.Result(res.Id" +
        ",max(res.creationDate) as creationDate) " +
        "from ExampleDAO res " +
        "where res.userId = :userId " +
        "GROUP BY res.Id" )
Page<Result> getPaginatedResult(@Param("userId") long userId,
                                                   Pageable pageable);
```

And While creating a Pageable instance -

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNum,pageSize,Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC,"creationDate"));
```

The '**creationDate**' in Pageable instance and Query should be same.